# Reinstalling server and SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, database-backup, database-restore

Due to some Windows issue, can't clean-up the WinSxS folder and the Disk Space process (cleanmgr.exe) makes the CPU going to 100% meaning that I am at 97% of disk usage, I am planning to reinstall the server where my SQL engine is running.

I know I have to backup the databases, fine with that. How do I backup the login and their rights ? I have got also some jobs I would like to backup. Anything else I should think of ? Should I backup and restore the master db or any other system databases ?

Consider I have got 72 databases and 85 logins so I wouldn't want to do that one x one.

My server is a Windows Server 2016 running a SQL Server 2016. The reinstallation of the OS and SQL Server engine will be done for me by my provider.

Comment: Voting to close as this really belongs to dba.stackexchange.com - this is extremely SQL Server specific and database servers have their own site. You are way more likely to get a good in depth answer there, especially given that login backup/restore is a problem in itself for sql server.

Comment: I didn't know dba.stackexchange.com, so fine for me if you want to close it, I'll post it there. Thanks TomTom

Comment: I know - most people do not know about it. That said, if you ever wonder where to find REAL sql level brutal questions answered - that is where the DBA's hang out ;) And SQL Server backup is TRICKY outside of the "oh, backup a single database".

Comment: no dont re-post ist, just flag your question for movement, it is the easier way. but you could also do [a linked server setup](https://serverfault.com/questions/88962/sql-server-to-sql-server-linked-server-setup?rq=1) and then unlink the old one? :)

Comment: While you certainly should be able to do this type of restore, this is not without risk and it sounds like the first time. Logons are one obvious objects to restore, but there's many other quirks like backup type/transaction log playback, etc.